# Finding the cursor text position in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, caret, jspinner

Is there a method to return the position of the character in the JTextField.   What I mean by that is if I have a JTextField
with some values in it.   For example, the field contains value
ABCDEFJ.   The user decides to put the cursor right after the
character 'C' to enter a new value.  Is there a method to get
position where he enters the new character.  In this example,
that would return a 3.

Comment: What is the actual use-case here?  It is looking like a `JSpinner` (or perhaps an editable `JComboBox`) would be a better component to use.

Comment: This is not a good question because you're asking for a specific code solution rather than how to implement a behavior. The actual solution to your desired behavior may involve a completely different approach. For instance, if you're trying to check a JTextField's input before it is complete, then perhaps what you really want to use is a DocumentFilter. So in the future, please tell us more about the overall problem that you want to solve, and less on how specifically you are trying to solve it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`JTextField.getCaretPosition()`

`JTextField.setCaretPosition(int pos)`

Comment: Is there a more direct method -- Like setting the position to a text offset from start of the string?

Comment: like this? `JTextField.setCaretPosition(anyPrecalculatedOffset)`

Answer (score 2):

Try getting use of `CaretListener` interface:

```
public class A extends JFrame implements CaretListener
{
  //Assume you have a text field.
  public A()
  {
    JTextField field = new JTextField("bla bla");
    field.addCaretListener(this);
    .....
  }

  public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e)
  {          
    int index = e.getDot();
    .....
  }
}
```

`getDot()` method of `CaretEvent` class returns the result you desire, you can assign it to a global variable to use later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29

Use an ActionListener to wait for an action. When the user types something, find the caret position.